# excel 'Refers to:' like control in C#

Tags: c#, vsto, formula

I'm working on VSTO application in C#. I've a Modal form, where I want to have a control similar to Excel's Name manager 'Refers to:' textbox. Whenever the control is in textbox, user can move to Excel sheets and select the appropriate range and that range gets added in the textbox. However, if the controls isn't in 'Refers to:' textbox, user cannot switch between excel sheets.

Is there anyway by which I could implement similar functionality?

Thanks

EDIT:
I figured out a way to do this. Application.InputBox gives a window wherein user can input required formula/range. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.inputbox?view=excel-pia

Answer (score 0):

Start by using [Excel InterOp object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/excel-object-model-overview?view=vs-2019)

Assuming you have an `Excel` or `Window` object reference to either the file or window you want to take control, you could use its property `Selection` to get that info from the Excel file and add it to your textbox.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out on how to do this and updated the post.